# Site Randomly Broken - String could not be parsed as XML

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have just viewed my site after the weekend to see the message String could not be parsed as XML.

Joomla 3.2.3, T3 Framework, Purity Template

If I manually type mydomain/blog I can access the blog and every other page, however my index page doesn't appear - just the error message '0 String could not be parsed as XML'.

I use a Joomlart template based on the T3 Framework (demo can be seen here http://purity_iii.demo.joomlart.com/). Usually this is a very stable framework.

My menu is set to XLayout - Features Intro, I have also changed this (to blog, and single article) and it makes no difference, however if I change the whole site template (to prostar) it works. So it's pointing to a tamplate/framework issue? I haven't made any template changes recently, nor any other core changes. No additional plugins or modules have been installed - seems to just have randomly broken.

I am still able to access the admin area, where I was able to change the template to prostar. I was able to update the T3 plugin as well, according to my install I am using the latest T3 version which is 2.3.0 and the latest remplate Purity version 1.0.0 Developer preview.

Can anybody shed some light on this issue?! I could probably re-install the template but I want to know what's going on if possible, so I can avoid this in future?

The only edit I did make was to the htaccess file - and it was to redirect non-www urls to www. This worked fine after the change and I don't think it's related.

Thanks

Comment: Have you performed any extension updates before the error occurred?

Comment: Try to disable caching to check if you can generate the error and check where it comes from.

Comment: > …the latest remplate Purity version 1.0.0 Developer preview. A Developer Preview version? It's not that hard to imagine that it may have a bug. It's probably sensible to not use a Developer preview version on a live site, unless you have tested it thoroughly on a development site first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I did check with Joomlart and this release is stable with all major bugs fixed. I think I may have found the issue, although I'm not quite sure how to 'fix' it. Last week I amended my .htaccess file by adding some redirect rules to the bottom. Once I deleted these re-direct rules the main page appeared again almost immediatley, so this is the issue. Once I troubleshoot it I will post again, thanks.

Comment: Thahnks for the suggestions however none of them worked, I think it's to do with changes in the .htaccess file regarding redirect rules. I'll post again later, thanks.

Comment: @johnny_s-- in the error message in your PHP error logs you should see a reference to the file / line where the error occurs. Do you see any? Also-- T3 has a system plugin that often causes issues. I'd try disabling these plugins one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the .htaccess file, I had added some rewrite rules which didn't come into effect immediately. Since removed and working again, thanks.